# Installing firebase on PyCharm?

Tags: firebase, pycharm

I am trying to install on firebase on PyCharm, but it's just throwing an error. 
I've already installed python-firebase in terminal but still no luck.

```
from firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://your_storage.firebaseio.com', None)
result = firebase.get('/users', None)
print result
{'1': 'John Doe', '2': 'Jane Doe'}
```

Is the code I'm trying to run.

Any help?

Comment: What is the error its throwing?

Comment: It's saying it can't find firebase, and when I try to install it it says that pip cannot be found although I installed it in the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pycharm, open 'Terminal'. In it run command

```
pip install firebase
```

After successful installation run your program.

Note:- For installation it required internet connectivity.